# Is the endian-ness of a QImage created from a uchar[] platform-dependent?

Tags: qt, endianness, qimage

QImage has a constructor QImage (uchar *data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format) that creates a QImage from an existing memory buffer.

Is the order of bytes (uchars) platform-dependent? If I put the values for alpha, red, green, and blue in it with increasing indices, alpha is swapped with blue and red is swapped with green. This indicates a problem with endian-ness.

I now wonder whether the endian-ness is platform-dependent or not. The Qt documentation does not say anything about this.

If it is NOT platform-dependent, I would just change the order of storing the values:

```
texture[ startIndex + 0 ] = pixelColor.blue();
texture[ startIndex + 1 ] = pixelColor.green();
texture[ startIndex + 2 ] = pixelColor.red();
texture[ startIndex + 3 ] = pixelColor.alpha();
```

If it *is* platform-dependent, I would create an array of uint32, store values computed as alpha << 24 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue, and reinterpret_cast the array before passing it to the QImage() constructor.

Best regards,

Jens

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the format. Formats that state the total number of bits in a pixel are endian-dependent. Like `Format_ARGB32` indicates a 32-bit integer whose highest 8 bits are alpha, which on a little endian machine, the same 8 bits are the last byte in the byte sequence.

Formats with individual bits in the sequence like `Format_RGB888` are not endian-dependent. `Format_RGB888` says the bytes are arranged in memory in R,G,B order regardless of endian.

To access bytes in the buffer, I would use `Q_BYTE_ORDER` macro to conditionally compile in the corresponding byte access code, instead of using shifts.

I personally use `Format_RGB888` since I don't deal with alpha directly in the image. That saves me the problem of dealing with endian difference.

Comment: "Formats with individual bits in the sequence like Format_RGB888 are not endian-dependent."

It seems `Format_RGB666` would still be endian dependent. It might only be safe to say that if the description includes "byte-ordered" or "halfword-ordered" that the channels actually flow using the stated order in memory, but otherwise they are formed as a full word (and thus flow backwards on a typical x86 endian CPU). `Format_RGB888` explicitly says "byte ordered", whereas `BGR888` does not ‍♀️.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Qt Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html):

> Warning: If you are accessing 32-bpp image data, cast the returned
>   pointer to QRgb* (QRgb has a 32-bit size) and use it to read/write the
>   pixel value. You cannot use the uchar* pointer directly, because the
>   pixel format depends on the byte order on the underlying platform. Use
>   qRed(), qGreen(), qBlue(), and qAlpha() to access the pixels.

Comment: Thanks. I would have expected such a warning in the documentation of the enum values of QImage::Format, not the function QImage::scanLine ...